# Rock paper scissors game not working

Tags: python

I made a script that would let me play rock paper scissors. I am not able to call a class. Why?

```
import random
player_choice = input("Choose rock paper or scissors")
class rock_paper_scissors:
    def __init__(self, player_choice, moves, ai_choice):
        self.player_choice
        self.moves = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
        ai_choice = random.choice(moves)
    for player_choice in rock_paper_scissors:
        if player_choice == "rock" and ai_choice == "scissors":
            print("You win Rock beat's scissors")
        elif ai_choice == "paper":
            print("You lose! Paper beats Rock")
        if player_choice == "paper" and ai_choice == "rock":
            print("You win! Paper beats rock!")
        elif ai_choice == "Scissors":
            print("You lose! Scissors beats paper!")
        if player_choice == scissors and ai_choice == paper:
            print("You win")
        elif ai_choice == rock:
            print("You lose! Rocky beats paper!")
        if player_choice == ai_choice:
            print("You tied!")
        if player_choice == scissors and ai_choice == paper:
            print("You win")
        elif ai_choice == rock:
            print("You lose! Rocky beats paper!")
        if player_choice == ai_choice:
            print("You tied!")
```

Error:

> NameError: name 'rock_paper_scissors' is not defined on line 8 in main.py

Comment: Please [edit] your post to indent that code block correctly.  See the Help Center's article on [markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details.  (Short version: Indent every line of the code block with 4 spaces... plus whatever indents the Python code had already.)

Comment: Fix this, it's unreadable.  Code lines need to be indented 4 or more spaces in SO.  The 4 spaces are stripped and the text is formatted as a code block.  Do it.

Comment: I rolled back my edit, because even with the edit, this code does not make sense. Please revise your code and make sure it is a proper representation of what you have in your own editor. Use the editing tools in the question to format the code properly.

Comment: The `for` loop makes no sense and won't work.  Why not define a method that is called to play the game, or handle a move?

Comment: None of this makes any sense.  Voting to close.

Comment: Start much, much smaller: first get yourself to a game that will echo back the player choice. But you're still a long way from that, with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more helpful to explain what needs to be fixed, I think:

- `self.player_choice` is undefined;
- You are passing `ai_choice` to the constructor and then explicitly overwriting its value inside;
- There is no need to pass `moves` to your constructor if you're going to define it inside anyway.
- You can't do a for loop over `rock_paper_scissors` because you haven't told Python how to iterate over a class;
- Your indentation is incorrect;
- You choose to use `elif` in place of `if` at arbitrary points, which is confusing ;
- Some of `scissors`, `rock`, `paper` are referred to as variables rather than enclosed in quotes to make a string. None of these references are defined.

This is how you should fix it, with better style:

```
import random

class Game(object): # it's considered good practice to inherit from `object`

    # this is a constructor where we declare all instance variables
    def __init__(self):

        # create a dictionary of what defeats what; accessible in all member
        # functions - I deliberately chose to do this to reduce the number
        # of if statements in your code and improve readability.

        self.victory_map = {"rock":"scissors", "paper":"rock", "scissors":"paper"}

    # a method to play only a single round
    def play(self):

        # Here I ask player's input, and make a random choice from only our
        # victory_map's keys

        player_choice = input("Type 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors' exactly")
        ai_choice = random.choice(self.victory_map.keys())

        # handle case where user types in something not in self.moves
        while player_choice not in self.victory_map:
              print("Type one of 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors' EXACTLY as written!")
              player_choice = input("Type 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors'")

        # This block takes care of the actual victory logic
        if self.victory_map[player_choice] == ai_choice:
             print("You win!")
        elif self.victory_map[ai_choice] == player_choice: 
             print("You lose")
        else:
             print("It's a draw.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_game = Game()
    while True:
        # infinite loop, causes you to play indefinitely
        new_game.play()
```

Comment: Thanks. This has been a learning experience

Answer (score 0):

There we a lot of strange things going on in your code. Firstly you are creating a meaningless instance of a rock_paper_scissors object. This isn't a situation where it's beneficial to create a object. Managing your rps object is more trouble than it's worth in an example like this. Secondly you forgot to wrap a lot of your strings with quotes.

I changed things like `ai_choice == rock:` to `ai_choice == "rock":` and removed the use of an RPS object and it works.

A little side note is that all these if statements are not a good way to decide who is the winner. Create a var of win conditions and reference that.

```
import random
player_choice = input("Choose rock paper or scissors ")
moves = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
ai_choice = random.choice(moves)


if player_choice == "rock" and ai_choice == "scissors":
    print("You win Rock beat's scissors")
elif ai_choice == "paper":
    print("You lose! Paper beats Rock")
if player_choice == "paper" and ai_choice == "rock":
    print("You win! Paper beats rock!")
elif ai_choice == "Scissors":
    print("You lose! Scissors beats paper!")
if player_choice == "scissors" and ai_choice == "paper":
    print("You win")
elif ai_choice == "rock":
    print("You lose! Rocky beats paper!")
if player_choice == ai_choice:
    print("You tied!")
if player_choice == "scissors" and ai_choice == "paper":
    print("You win")
elif ai_choice == "rock":
    print("You lose! Rocky beats paper!")
if player_choice == ai_choice:
    print("You tied!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import random

# Ask user for info
player_input = input("Choose rock paper or scissors: ")


# Main class
class rock_paper_scissors:

    # Initialiser method
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player_choice = player
        self.moves = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
        self.ai_choice = random.choice(self.moves)

    # Method to check who won
    def checkWhoWon(self):
        if self.player_choice == "rock" and self.ai_choice == "scissors":
            print("You win Rock beat's scissors")
        elif self.ai_choice == "paper":
            print("You lose! Paper beats Rock")
        if self.player_choice == "paper" and self.ai_choice == "rock":
            print("You win! Paper beats rock!")
        elif self.ai_choice == "Scissors":
            print("You lose! Scissors beats paper!")
        if self.player_choice == "scissors" and self.ai_choice == "paper":
            print("You win")
        elif self.ai_choice == "rock":
            print("You lose! Rocky beats paper!")
        if self.player_choice == self.ai_choice:
            print("You tied!")
        if self.player_choice == "scissors" and self.ai_choice == "paper":
            print("You win")
        elif self.ai_choice == "rock":
            print("You lose! Rocky beats paper!")
        if self.player_choice == self.ai_choice:
            print("You tied!")


# Create an object called main from the class "rock_paper_scissors"
Main = rock_paper_scissors(player_input)
# Call the method to check who won
Main.checkWhoWon()
```